# Conditions in IF Statements requires values to be specified explicitly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have created a template that displays items from a loop, Within the loop there is a condition, but the condition does not work unless specified explicitly.

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>

    {% for project in projects %}
        {% if user.username == 'testuser' %}
            <h5>{{ project.title }}</h5>
            <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
            <p>{{ project.objectives }}</p>
            <pre>{{ project.score }}</pre>
            <pre>{{ project.student_id }}</pre>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

The above code works perfectly and returns the records assigned to the user named testuser.

But if I write the code as below, it skips all records

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

    <h3>{{ user.username }}</h3>

    {% for project in projects %}
        {% if user.username == project.student_id %}
            <h5>{{ project.title }}</h5>
            <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
            <p>{{ project.objectives }}</p>
            <pre>{{ project.score }}</pre>
            <pre>{{ project.student_id }}</pre>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I have added the code from the model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    objectives = models.TextField()
    score = models.IntegerField()
    #file = models.FileField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `student_id` is probably a `ForeignKey` to a `User` object, right? Can you share the relevant models please?

Comment: Yes, student_id is a foreign key

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `student_id` is a `User` object, not a *string*, so here you are comparing a string (the `username`) with a `User` object, and a `User` with username `'testuser'`, is *not* the same as a string `'testuser'`.

The most elegant solution is probably to compare the user with the user, so:

```
{% if user == project.student_id %}
```

So we omit the `.username`, and compare a `User` object with a `User` object.

> **Note**: enumeration (especially in a template, but also in the Django layer itself), is *not* efficient, you should make a query that
>   does the filtering for you.
>
> You can filter a queryset with:
>
> ```
> user_projects = Project.objects.filter(student_id=request.user)
> ```
>
> in your view to obtain only projects for which the logged in user is
>   the student.

> **Note**: A `ForeignKey` usually does *not* have an `_id` suffix. Django will automatically add an extra field named `fieldname_id` that
>   stores the primary key to which the foreign key refers. After all, a
>   `ForeignKey` in Django will lazy load the related object.

Comment: Thanks Willem, I am in the process of chiseling through Django step by step. To use `request.user` which library should be imported?

Comment: @Sunil: the `request` is just the request object that is passed to your view function. For a class-based view, it is `self.request.user`.